# PayPal & PHP - Set no shipping

Tags: php, paypal

I'm in the process of creating a payment with PayPal with their REST API.

I have everything set up and working but when I create a WebProfile and call `setNoShipping(1)`, nothing changes:

[image: PayPal]

My code:

```
$inputFields = new InputFields();
$inputFields->setNoShipping(1)

$webProfile = new WebProfile();
$webProfile->setName('test' . uniqid())->setInputFields($inputFields);
```

And according to [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32358852/paypal-rest-api-unable-to-set-landing-page-to-billing) it's not possible, but is that **still** the case 1 year later?

Comment: As far as I know, every company I bought at I had to add a shipping address, even when no shipping is required, so maybe it's not possible *yet*. :/

Comment: I'm still not seeing in the REST  API reference.  This is one of the reasons I still use the NVP / SOAP APIs instead.  They are much more mature than REST at this point, and they continue to build on those, too, so I'm not sure how/when REST will ever catch up.

Comment: If you want to switch to the Classic API you can use NOSHIPPING as expected.  I have a [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) that makes it very quick and easy for you to setup classic API calls.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem but after some research and many try & error i got it to work.

You have to "create" the profile and add its id to the Payment.

```
[...]
$webProfileId = $webProfile->create($apiContext)->getId();

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setExperienceProfileId($webProfileId);
```